# Skype:Bot not replying

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am developing my first NodeJS bot with Bot builder Framework. Bot is successfully running on Emulator but when I registered the Bot and tried to test in skype - it doesn't reply anything.

**More Info**

- During the Bot registration, I gave endpoint url as given from ngrok.exe 
  and appended '/api/messages'
- I added Skype channel - bot shows online
- app.js (containing restify) & ngrok both are running on localhost
- I added Microsoft App Id inside connector as follows:

```

```
 var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    //appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    //appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
    appId: MY APP ID HERE,
    appPassword: MY APP PASSWORD HERE
});
```

```

Any help is appreciated!
Happy to provide more details, if needed.

Comment: Please post the code of your bot. are you expecting an attachment?